# Install different version of Lotus notes on same computer where the other version of Lotus notes is already isntalled

Tags: lotus-notes

I would like to install Lotus Notes 7/designer/client/admin on same computer probably in other drive, where we have already installed Lotus notes 9. therefore I would like to know if this would create any conflict ? or any probable issues ? or some one can please explain me how to do that any guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid the pitfalls, by installing a virtual system on your machine (VMWare or VirtualBox) and running it from there. When you use a shared folder from the host system, all your data will be directly accessible on the host. You can have several virtual machines, each for one version of Notes, or for one client needing special setup or different user ids.

Answer (score 1):

As Notes 7 (and all versions before) do not even need an installation to work the answer is easily given: just install the client to another machine (even a virtual machine) and copy over Program + Data Diectory to your pc. Then you only need to adjust notes.ini (if you changed path when copying) and create a shortcut to launch notes7. Create a shortcut to Notes7ProgramDirectory\nlnotes.exe =Notes7ProgramDirectory\notes.ini

Now you can launch Notes7 after Notes9 is already launched. The other way around will not work: if notes7 is already started, then Notes9 will not start in parallel.